# Is there any way to send signal from hdmi to ethernet converters (which have no ip) over my network

Tags: networking, router, ip, ethernet, video-conversion

I'm a bit of a networking beginner and I'm looking to send video over my network. I was thinking something like below;

Camera -> hdmi/cat5 converter -> cat5 -> *network* -> cat5 -> hdmi/cat5 converter -> computer/capture card.

I had searched for around 2 hours earlier to find any solutions. I'm not sure if I'm not searching for the right terminology.

As for my question is there any way to direct traffic through a network that didn't originate from an ip address? i.e. can I assign an ip to a physical port on my router or something? Maybe my issue is having that idea stuck in my head, in which case are there any solutions you would recommend?

P.S. I know there are expensive hdmi to ip converters but I've got these hdmi to ethernet converters from a previous project and would like to use them.

Thanks

Comment: By the way, HDMI is very much designed to drive displays, rather than acting as a PC input from a camera. If you have a camera with an HDMI output, it's probably so you can display what you just shot on your display. It should have some other interface for actually transferring the footage to a computer. I believe studio cameras that do live HD usually have SDI outputs. HDMI would be a poor choice for live streaming from a camera to anything other than directly to a display, and it would be an even worse choice for transferring footage that was already recorded to the camera's local storage.

Comment: I appreciate that but there's an extremely limited budget and the cheapest options output live with a hdmi cable that's the main reasons for using it, but thank you for the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

Your converters are HDMI to Cat 5, not HDMI to Ethernet.

That is, they use the same kind of cable, but they send a completely different, incompatible kind of signal over that cable. You cannot mix the two.